How to show a notification before 30 secs of idle session timeout bn-ng-idle Angular?
I am using bn-ng-idle npm package to auto logout user due to inactivity. I have implemented it as per the documentation and it is working fine.
I also want to show an alert or a dialogue box before 30 secs of auto logout. If the user does some activity then the alert should get closed, otherwise the user must get logged out after 30 secs.
Below is the initial implementation
idleSessionTimeout() {
    const idleTimeout = configuration.idleSessionTimoutThreshold;
    this.bnIdle.startWatching(idleTimeout).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res) {
        this.bnIdle.stopTimer();
        localStorage.setItem('appStorage', JSON.stringify({}));
        this.route.navigateByUrl('/login');
      }
    });
  }

I tried to create a timer with 30 secs less than actual timeout period. But it is not working fine as the alert is only getting generated once. once I do some activity and close the alert after that the alert does not get generated.
idleSessionTimeout() {
    const idleTimeout = configuration.idleSessionTimoutThreshold;
    const alertTime = idleTimeout - 30; // 30 seconds before idle timeout

    this.bnIdle.startWatching(idleTimeout).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res) {
        this.bnIdle.stopTimer();
        localStorage.setItem('appStorage', JSON.stringify({}));
        this.route.navigateByUrl('/login');
      }
    });
  
    // Show alert 30 seconds before idle timeout
    timer(alertTime * 1000).subscribe(() => {
      alert('Your session will expire in 30 seconds. Please continue your activity to keep the session active.');
    });
  }


You could simply have two timers, one for showing the popup before 30 seconds and another that triggers the logout, since you are using a library we cannot customize the code, instead we can use this method.
Also do not forget to unsubscribe the same, which might give you memory leaks.
...
private sub: Subscription = new Subscription();
...

...
idleSessionTimeout() {
    const idleTimeout = configuration.idleSessionTimoutThreshold;
    const alertTime = idleTimeout - 30; // 30 seconds before idle timeout
    this.sub.add(
    this.bnIdle.startWatching(idleTimeout).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res) {
        this.bnIdle.stopTimer();
        localStorage.setItem('appStorage', JSON.stringify({}));
        this.route.navigateByUrl('/login');
      }
    })
    );
  
    // Show alert 30 seconds before idle timeout
    this.sub.add(
    this.bnIdle.startWatching(alertTime).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res) {
        alert('Your session will expire in 30 seconds. Please continue your activity to keep the session active.');
      }
    })
    );
}
...

...
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
}

